# Strip excess padding from a string

Tags: autohotkey

I asked a question earlier today and got a really quick answer from llbrink.  I really should have asked that question before I spent several hours trying to find an answer.

So - here's another question that I have never found an answer for (although I have created a work-around which seems very cludgy).

My AHK program asks the user for a login name.  The program then compares the login name with an existing list of names in a file.

The login name in the file may contain spaces, but there are never spaces at the beginning of the name.  When the user enters the name, he may include spaces at the beginning.  This means that when my program compares the name with those in the file, it can not find a match (because of the extra spaces).

I want to find a way of stripping the spaces from the beginning of the input.

My work-round has been to split the input string into an array (which does ignore leading spaces) and then use the first element of the array.  This is my code :

```
name := DoStrip(name)

DoStrip(xyz) ; strip leading and trailing spaces from string
{
  StringSplit, out, xyz, `,, %A_Space%
  Return out1
}
```

This seems to be a very laboured way to do it - is there a better way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your example if it works on all cases.

There is a much simpler way; just use [Autotrim](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/AutoTrim.htm) which works like this.

```
AutoTrim, On ; not required it is on by default
my_variable = %my_variable%
```

There are also [many](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm) other [different](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExReplace.htm) [ways](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringTrimLeft.htm) [to trim](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringGetPos.htm) string in autohotkey,
which you can combine into something useful.

Comment: Thanks Armin. I looked all over for "trim", "strip", etc.  - but never found Auto trim.   That's just the job.

Comment: @Armin, I just added a quick example that'll save future visitors a trip.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand You forgot to add AutoTrim, On. Please be accurate when editing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `#LTrim` and `#RTrim` to remove white spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string.

Comment: I thought that this was to remove spaces at the beginning of a string in a 'continuation section' - typically to remove indentation in a Gui text block.  I can't make it work on individual variables.